# How do I the max limit (3200 tweets) using Twitter's API (1.1)

Tags: php, refactoring, twitter

I have been able to do it but it's in a rather 'ugly' way.

One problem I'm facing with refactoring is that I need to call 'max_id' but I need to use a placeholder until I make the first call. I've tried using 'null' and '' for $max_id but neither work. Also, I have a feeling it could be written without using a manual 'for' loop.

So far this is my code:

```
  $i = 1;
  $content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'username', 'count' => '200'));
  foreach ($content as $item) {
    echo $i . " : " . $item->text;
    echo("<hr>");
    $i++;
  }
  $lastTweet = end($content);
  $max_id = $lastTweet->id_str;

  for ($l = 0; $l<15; $l++) {
    $content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'username', 'count' => '200', 'max_id' => $max_id));
    foreach ($content as $item) {
      echo $i . " : " . $item->text;
      echo("<hr>");
      $i++;
    }
    $lastTweet = end($content);
    $max_id = $lastTweet->id_str;
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not beautiful, but inside the loop couldn't you just set a test variable. Sort of like a first time through instance or will that ruin the point of refactoring?

```
$maxID = false;
if(!$maxID) $content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'username', 'count' => '200'));
else { $content = $connection->get('statuses/user_timeline', array('screen_name' => 'username', 'count' => '200', 'max_id' => $max_id)); 
$maxID = true; }
```

Instead of a for loop if you're careful you could probably get away with a while loop() that goes off the count of your items returned then just increment that variable by the number of tweets returned on each pass. Just never accidentally let your while loop run forever, or you can say goodbye to twitter api requests for awhile.

```
$countTweets = 0;
 while($countTweets < 3200)
 { //code for your calls, do what you gotta do
   $countTweets += count($content);
 }
```

I use something very similar to what you have, except i just merge the next set of tweets to a total array then work off that big list of tweets. I also just test count of total merged array instead of adding to a count variable.